# ASP.NET JQuery location.reload with clear session/viewstate

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback, session-state, viewstate

i have a textbox with jquery autocomplete event and a button. the button function is for reload the page. but, after i click on them why the textbox still displaying the text? i've done with this code but nothing

```
 self.clear = function () {
       //location.reload(true); Doesn't work to IE neither Firefox;
       //also, hash tags must be removed or no postback will occur.
       window.location.href = window.location.href + '?eraseCache=true';
 };
```

the question is, what am i doing wrong with this code? i want to clear the texts when the button is clicked to reload/postback the page. any suggestion for help? thanks.

Comment: Did you try `autocomplete="off"` on your text boxes?

Comment: i was tried, but nothing

Comment: What does your server code do with the eraseCache parameter?

Comment: nothing, just want to make sure all of the viewstate or session has released, so that the textbox has no values anymore when the page is postback. it was fixed now. my bad my button is submit type, i was changed it to `input type="button"` and works. i just mistake in the click event

Comment: ok. Out of interest, wtthy would you bother to pass a querystring parameter that isn't actually used? If the server is ignoring the "eraseCache" parameter, why are you sending it?